# React-spring useTransitions Error no typescript

Tags: react, typescript

eu estou com um problema, to replicando um código que vi na net,
mas ele ta me dando erro na tipagem do Typescript.
O código está exatamente igual, porém está me retornando erro na tipagem das
props e eu não to conseguindo arrumar.

O erro é o seguinte:

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'from' does not
> exist in type 'any[]'. TS2345

Eu tentei procurar as tipagens do pacote a parte para tentar resolver, porém não achei nada.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, serei muito grato.

```
const ToastContainer: React.FC<ToastContainerProps> = ({ messages }) => {
  const ref = useRef();
  const messagesWithTransitions = useTransition(
    messages,
    (message: ToastMessage) => message.id,
    {
      from: { right: '-120%' },
      enter: { right: '0%' },
      leave: { right: '-120%' },
    },
  );

  return (
    <Container>
      {messagesWithTransitions.map(({ item, key, props }) => (
        <Toast key={key} message={item} />
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: Mostre as tipagens `ToastContainerProps` e `ToastMessage`.

Comment: O erro desaparecerá se você remover `(message: ToastMessage) => message.id,`

Comment: Galera, consegui resolver voltando uma versão anterior do React Spring, mas achei bem estranho. Eu havia tentado o método de remover a key, ``` (message: ToastMessage) => message.id``` porém sem sucesso.